# Запись данных тестового покрытия не работает с русским именем пользователя

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

Я хочу проверить покрытие теста, запускаю через run 'Test in'Lwsson_3"with Coverage  в итоге получаю ошибку

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.coverage.main.CoveragePremain.premain(CoveragePremain.java:66)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.intellij.rt.coverage.instrumentation.Instrumentator.premain(Instrumentator.java:64)
    ... 11 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Process finished with exit code 1
Exception in thread "main"
```

Answer (score 2):

Я никогда не сталкивался, но нагуглил за минуту. Это [зарегистрированный баг](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5941) связанный с наличием кириллических символов в пути к каталогу временных файлов. У вас видимо имя пользователя кириллическое. Решается добавлением в файлы **idea.exe.vmoptions** и **idea64.exe.vmoptions** строки `-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Temp`

Comment: Сергей, извиняюсь а вы не подскажите как добавить эту строку в эти файлы

Comment: В смысле? Открываете их любым текстовым редактором, вписываете строку, сохраняете.